# Join two objects seamlessly

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode, sculpting

I’ve been using Blender for a few weeks, mostly downloading free assets and creating scenes, lightings, materials and animations, so I didn’t make much practice on modeling and sculpting.

[image: Pic]

I need to merge these two separated parts of a character (I had to apply different edits and modifier on each of them, so I’ve used a Boolean modifier with a cube to subtract the parts, worked on them separately, and then I wanted to re-merge them;’when I do, both using a Boolean union or other few methods, also tried different tutorials in edit mode, but I still get the same result as shown in picture, where the borders get some issues; I think the main problem is bad topology and different subdivisions on the two individual parts, is there a not too complicated way to fix this without having to learn too much about edit mode and topology? In the end I just really need to get a good shading in those joints areas.

Any help would be appreciated, I’ve been on this for hours without being able to solve it

Comment: you could try weld modifier...

Comment: You could try a Merge by Distance or a Remesh, but anyway if you plan to animate you'll need to retopologize

Comment: Make sure they are 1 object (`CTRL-j`) then remesh (in the Object Data Properties tab). Then in sculpt mode use the smooth brush to iron out the seam lines.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the replies! i've tried both weld and merge by distance with poor results, so i checked some topology tutorials and worked on the model in edit mode, the main issue was that i've made a really bad job to begin with, with different faces density and shapes for each part; in the end i've solved deleting the vertices in the contact areas and bridging them manually, took a lot of effort and probably wasn't the smartest way but in the end it worked; then i've applied a multiresolution modifier and it miraculously fixed the remaining issues.

Comment: On another matter: I couldn't use the remesh modifier because that was the one that got me into trouble in the first place (i was getting too low details on the fingers of the model, they were becoming webbed like the paws of a goose); if i were to fix that how would you do it in the simplest way? also tried the remesh + shrinkwrap method on the original copy of the model, but i was getting more issues than the ones i was trying to fix :(